# Scramble latitude longitude coordinates within 100m radius with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, math, latitude-longitude

Title says it all, I need to scramble lat/lon coordinates within 100m radius for privacy reasons. I'm just horrible at maths and can't figure out how to convert 100m to lat/lon...

Eg I would have a location like:

```
lat: 52.5037086
lng: 13.434223100000054
```

Need to scramble this within 100m radius randomly, ie the furthest the generated coordinates can be from the original coordinates in any direction is 100m.

I've seen this formula around:

```
d = acos( sin(φ1)⋅sin(φ2) + cos(φ1)⋅cos(φ2)⋅cos(Δλ) ) ⋅ R

where:  
    φ = latitude, λ = longitude
    R = radius of earth
    d = distance between the points
```

No idea how to accomplish this in JavaScript, though. These "points" are markers within a Google Map if it makes a difference.

To be honest, it doesn't even need to be a circle, just random location within 100m x 100m square would work as well.

Comment: So basically you need a 100 meter radius circular area whose center should be ( 52.5037086, 13.434223100000054) right ?

Comment: Yes, and then somehow use math.random to pick a point within that radius.

Answer (score 0):

At such small extents, we can work with a linear approximation of the problem and a spherical earth model.

Consider, you are at a position `(lat, long)`. Then, increasing `lat` by 1° results in a distance from the original point of `d_lat = Pi * R * 1°/180°` (simple perimeter of a circle).

Similarly, increasing `long` by 1° results in a distance of `d_long = cos(lat) * Pi * R * 1°/180°`.

Then, you can calculate the maximum change of latitude and longitude:

```
maxChangeLatitude  = 100 m / d_lat
maxChangeLongitude = 100 m / d_long
```

Find a random point in this square and you have your point:

```
newLat  = lat  + (2 * Math.random() - 1) * maxChangeLatitude;
newLong = long + (2 * Math.random() - 1) * maxChangeLongitude;
```